# How to check if variable is blank in CL?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I have this piece of code.

```
IF         COND(%TRIM(&BLANK_VAR) *EQ '') THEN(DO)
            CALL       PGM(MY_PROGRAM) PARM(&BLANK_VAR)
ENDDO
```

I would like to check if `&BLANK_VAR` is an empty string. However my program won't compile because of error message:

```
* CPD0126 30  Operand not valid or operator missing in COND.
```

Is this an issue with `%TRIM`? I tried using `%LEN` but it gives me lenght of the variable declared, not the actual data inside.

`&BLANK_VAR` is 10 characters in length.
Do I have to do:

```
IF COND(&BLANK_VAR *EQ '          ')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to simply add an actual space in your two single quotes:

```
IF         COND(%TRIM(&BLANK_VAR) *EQ ' ') THEN(DO)
            CALL       PGM(MY_PROGRAM) PARM(&BLANK_VAR)
ENDDO
```

The reason you are getting the error is that two `'` right next to each other is acting as an escaped single quote.  This typically allows you to embed single quotes into a literal string but in this case it looks to the compiler like you have an invalid single character string.

Comment: There is no BUILT-IN in CLLE for *BLANKS.  Using that code will compare the character fields against the string containing the text '*BLANKS'.
The first comparison using single quote blank single quote is correct.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Thanks.  I don't use CL all that often.  I have removed that suggestion from my answer.